# Function which is equal to a holomorphic function at 3 points

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F$ be a function from $\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$ to $\mathbb{D}$. Suppose $F$ is such that for each $w_{1}, w_{2}, w_{3} \in \mathbb{D}$, there exists a holomorphic $f_{w_{1}, w_{2}, w_{3}}: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ such that $f_{w_{1}, w_{2}, w_{3}}(w_{j}) = F(w_{j})$ for $j = 1, 2, 3$. Why must $F$ must holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be a closed disk contained in $\mathbb D$ and centred at $p$.  Using Cauchy's estimates, there  is a constant $M(K)$ such that for any holomorphic $f: {\mathbb D} \to \mathbb D$ and $z \in K$,
$$\left|\dfrac{f(z) - f(p)}{z-p} - f'(p)\right| \le M(K) |p - z|$$

So if we take two sequences $w_j$ and $z_j$ converging to, but not equal to,
$p$, then $$\lim_{j \to \infty} \left|\dfrac{F(w_j) - F(p)}{w_j - p} - \dfrac{F(z_j) - F(p)}{z_j - p} \right| = 0 $$
This implies that
$\lim_{z \to p} \dfrac{F(z) - F(p)}{z - p}$ exists, which says $F$ is holomorphic.

Comment: How did you get the first centered equation from the Cauchy estimates?

Comment: $$\dfrac{f(z) - f(p)}{z-p} - f'(p) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma f(\zeta) \left( \dfrac{1}{(\zeta - z)(z-p)} - \dfrac{1}{(\zeta -p)(z-p)} - \dfrac{1}{(\zeta-p)^2} \right)\; d\zeta$$
$$ = \dfrac{z-p}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma \dfrac{f(\zeta)\; d\zeta}{(\zeta-p)^2 (\zeta-z)} $$